# jQuery animated resize on click?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to resize a image from one of my Divs but they all end up resizing but not in order.

How can i make sure they do it individually? Also, how can I do something when on click the picture will go to its original size?

Here's my HTML:

```
<img class="i1" border="0" src="Main Picture Gallery/1.JPG" alt="Edge Hill near lake" width="204" height="153" />
<img class="i2" border="0" src="Main Picture Gallery/2.JPG" alt="Edge hill libary" width="204" height="153" />
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script>    
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".i1, .i2").animate({height:'612'})
    $(".i1, .i2").animate({width:'816'})
});         
</script>
```

Comment: add 'px' next to every width or height value

Comment: You're attaching an event handler to the document, and changing all elements with those classes, so no suprises there ?

Comment: I asked for help, if you cannot help, please just leave this alone :)

Comment: It works with out withing the adding of "px" mate.

Comment: That was help! The document is "everything", so clicking anywhere will animate all elements with the classes i1 and i2 etc.

Comment: what do you mean individually? where is the problem now?

Comment: Okay BUT when i do put down other things such as #gallery it just does NOT work. With document it works just fine. anymore help?

Comment: The problem is that the fact when i click on ONE image the others also resize their selfs. BUT i just want i to resize individually and then when its been clicked again i want it to go to its original size.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the code in document ready. If the script comes before the markup in your file, the DOM would'nt be ready, and the only thing you could access would be the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $(".i1, .i2").on('click', function() {

        var h = $(this).height();
        $(this).animate({
            height: (h < 600 ? 612 : 153), 
            width : (h < 600 ? 816 : 204)
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZbrw/)

Comment: Good shout on the reversal, but I think OP wants them **both** to animate, one after the other?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you very much mate. Matt, he got it spot on, sorry if my explaining was not very great.

Comment: @JushOv - feel free to accept it, if it's what you where looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

First, you're attaching your `click` to `document`, it should be `$(".il, .i2").click`.

Next, in order to animate them individually, use the callback function of `animate` to ensure one has completed before the other starts.

Try this:

```
$(".i1, .i2").click(function() {
    $(".i1").animate({height:'612', width: '816'}, 1000, function () {
        $(".i2").animate({height:'612', width: '816'});
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UqKZq/1/)

Comment: change `$(".il, .i2")` to `$(".i1, .i2")` and it's good if he wants both to run on one click.

Comment: @Biotox Done, thanks :). Weirdly JSFiddle shows `1` and `l` the same.

Comment: I think the difference is in the feet on the `l`. I was confused at first too.